# In Power BI Desktop, how can I group all measures together (instead of placing under different tables)?

Tags: powerbi, dax, tabular, measure

Tableau automatically groups measures together but Power BI Desktop doesn't natively support this. I find it annoying to have to place measures under imported tables as the measures don't really belong to those "parent tables" (and quite often take input from multiple tables — which one would you consider the "parent"?)

So I experimented with some workarounds and I'm sharing the successful (as of the date of this post) ones here:

Answer (score 4):

- **Method 1** (*recommended*): **"Model" view > "Enter data"** to enter a **manual data table**. Give a name like "_Measures_" so it appears on top of tables, and keep only the default dummy column "Column". Create/move measures under it, then right click to **delete** that "Column". Now you're left with a blank table that groups those measures under it.
- **Method 2**: **"Data" view > "New table"** to create a **DAX calculated table**. Rest the same as above, except that for a DAX calculated table you can't delete the dummy column but instead you can **hide** it.
- You can also "Enter data" using Power Query Editor but I don't recommend going with that extra step -- workarounds are supposed to be quick (and dirty) anyways!

Final results look like this (note the **difference of the icons**):

[image: Demo of measure grouping workarounds]

Comment: Future readers may also be interested in [display folders](https://radacad.com/organize-power-bi-dax-measures-in-folders).

Comment: Good tip! A word of caution is you might not be able to delete the display (sub)folders once created.

Anyways I think Power BI should really work on a feature that not only visually, but also logically organizes the measures, something like a "measures tree" that shows which measure references which measure/table column, regardless where they are grouped.